# Best practises for case style selects with widening conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

We are designing a solution that will interrogate transactional data in order to return matching based on the first set of rules that returns a result, where each select is wider than the previous. The goal is to get the narrowest search that returns a result.

Here is an illustration. Consider a scenario with vehicle data where we have been given the following three values:

1. VIN of a vehicle
2. Registration No of a vehicle
3. City where the vehicle is in

We then want to interrogate transactional data to return matches against that value. An important distinction is that *it can be a one to many match* since the transactional data has additional relationships which mean that duplicate vehicles may reside in the transactional data. In a one to many match, we require all the matched IDs from the matching process

The order that we want to interrogate the data is as follows (as an illustration):

From the transactional data:

- Return all vehicles that have a matching VIN and City

If none exist:

- Return all vehicles that have a matching VIN

If none exist:

- Return all vehicles that have a matching Rego and City

This example has only three widening conditions, however, in our application it will actually be around 8.

This could be done in a sequential manner, as illustrated below, however that doesn't feel correct, there is probably a better set based operation to do it, but I can't think how to create it.

Here is the way it could be done sequentially:

```
-- assume these values are passed in
declare @vin varchar(50) = 'abcdefg'
declare @rego varchar(50) = '123456'
declare @city = 'Sydney'

-- create a table to hold the results
declare @ids table(id int)

-- try the narrowest search: matching VIN and City
insert into @ids(id)
select id from TransactionalData where Vin = @vin and City = @city

if ((select count(*) from @ids ) = 0)
begin
  -- try the next narrowest search: matching VIN
  insert into @ids(id)
  select id from TransactionalData where Vin = @vin

  if ((select count(*) from @ids ) = 0)
  begin
    -- try the next narrowest search: matching Rego and City
    insert into @ids(id)
    select id from trasnactionaldata where Rego = @rego and City = @city
  end
end

-- at this point, @ids will contain the ids from the narrowest search
```

It would work, but it doesn't seem like the correct approach. Can anyone suggest how to do it in a single set based opperation?

Many thanks

Comment: A thought that has occurred to me could be to create a temporary table and insert all values from the transactional database where *any* conditions match and then perform the narrowing of the data on that subset. It would likely be more efficient, but doing the sequential widening still feels clumbsy.

Comment: Are `TransactionalData` and `trasnactionaldata` tables differnet tables or typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we can use a column to represent priority which means you expect to insert order by `CASE WHEN` expression

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT id, CASE WHEN Vin = @vin and City = @city THEN 3 
                    WHEN Vin = @vin THEN 2 
                    WHEN Rego = @rego and City = @cit THEN 1 
                END priority 
  FROM TransactionalData where (Vin = @vin and City = @city) OR (Vin = @vin) OR (Rego = @rego and City = @city)
)
INSERT INTO @ids(id)
SELECT id
FROM CTE c 
WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) FROM CTE)
```

Comment: You can actually remove the `city=@city` condition from the where clause as the rest of the logic takes care of it.

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach, along with the one that JohanB has suggested, and I will do an approach like that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. You specify the required condition in the `WHERE` clause and then do a match count on the result and rank it

```
select *,
       match_cnt = case when td.vin  = @vin then 1 else 0 end
                 + case when td.rego = @rego then 1 else 0 end
                 + case when td.city = @city then 1 else 0 end
from   TransactionalData td
where  td.vin  = @vin
or     td.rego = @rego
or     td.city = @city
order by match_cnt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT`

You could also use `CASE`

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        CASE 
            WHEN Vin = @vin and City = @city then 1
            WHEN Vin = @vin then 2
            WHEN Rego = @rego and City = @city then 3
        END as lvl
    FROM TransactionalData
)
INSERT into @ids(id) 
SELECT 
    id 
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE
    lvl = (SELECT MIN(lvl) FROM CTE)
```

But your approach is correct

Comment: You probably want some form of `where` clause to avoid having to read the entire database.